# calcHist with multiple channels in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compute a 3D 2x2x2 RGB histogram with openCV with `cv::calcHist`.  However I don't understand how `calcHist` works with multiple channels.  I want it to select one of two red layer of bins `i`, one of two green layer of bins `j` and one of two blue layer of bins `k` and store the result into the corresponding triple-indexed bin `bins[i][j][k]`.  But that's not what it's doing.

The following loop works fine

```
int bin_index(const float x, unsigned int nbins)
{
    return std::min(static_cast<unsigned int>(x*nbins), nbins - 1);
}

//...

for(cv::Point pixel_idx : all possible pixel positions)
{
    int red_idx = bin_index(image(pixel_idx)[0], number_of_red_bins);
    int green_idx = bin_index(image(pixel_idx)[0], number_of_green_bins);
    int blue_idx = bin_index(image(pixel_idx)[0], number_of_blue_bins);
    histogram[blue_idx * number_of_green_bins * number_of_red_bins 
        + green_idx * number_of_red_bins + red_idx] += 1;
}
```

But the following usage of cv::calcHist yield a different result

```
cv::Mat block = image(rect of the patch);
const int channels[] = {0, 1, 2};
const int histSize[] = {number_of_red_bins, number_of_green_bins, number_of_blue_bins};
constexpr int histSizeDims = sizeof(histSize) / sizeof(const int);
const float range[] {0.0f, 1.001f};
const float* histRanges[] = {range, range, range};
cv::Mat result;

cv::calcHist(
        &block,
        1,
        channels,
        cv::Mat(),
        result,
        histSizeDims,
        histSize,
        histRanges,
        true, false);
```

Can you tell me how how calcHist behaves with multi-dimentional histograms ?  Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your own histogram function looks faulty; for the `red_idx` and so on, you're grabbing the first color for each index (`image(pixel_idx)[0]` for all three colors). Shouldn't this be `[0]` for blue, `[1]` for green, `[2]` for red? Also you're indexing the histogram with `rgb_blue_idx` which isn't defined above. Do check the [histogram tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html). It looks like you're using the OpenCV call correctly, and I've used it often to success---I think your custom histogram is at fault.

Comment: Another small issue: the `histSize[]`in the second call has `number_of_red_bins` repeated. It's really difficult to type the proper use for you as it's very unclear whether you're using RGB or BGR ordering for your channels.

Comment: I cut a snipped of my code and renamed some variables, but I missed that `rgb_blue_idx` which should be `blue_idx`.  Fixed with the second `number_of_red_bins`.  As for the _rgb_ to _bgr_ reordering by weird indexing, I don't really mind for now.  Thanks for the tutorial, but as all examples I could find, it uses a histogram dimensionality of _1_ whereas I want one of _3_ and how calcHist behaves in higher histogram dimensions is precisely what I don't understand.

Comment: So I haven't used it in C++, but I have used the 3D histogram in OpenCV with Python and I got identical results to numpy's 3D histogram, and my call looks the same as yours so again I think you *are* using the OpenCV function correctly. This is where the issue is in your own histogram I think; for all three colors you're doing `image(pixel_idx)[0]` which is just grabbing the blue channel every time, these should be `[0]` for blue, `[1]` for green, and `[2]` for red (if using the OpenCV default BGR ordering). Can you edit with a [*complete* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?